Balance of payment under double entry bookkeeping
Assume that during a certain period, Taiwanese residents engage in the following three economic transactions with foreign residents:
A. Taiwan exports $3 million worth of goods to the United States, and the American importer pays by depositing the funds into the Taiwanese exporter’s account in the United States.
B. Taiwan donates $1 million worth of goods to Palau.
C. A Taiwanese company purchases $3.5 million worth of U.S. government bonds, using its deposits in the United States for payment.
Record the above three economic activities using double-entry bookkeeping for the balance of payments accounts (including the account, left column debit/right column credit, and transaction amount for each). Finally, create a table to summarize and calculate the balances of the current account and the financial account resulting from the above economic activities.

Please help me check if my table is right. Thank you!!
